# Rows not sorted after concat

Tags: python, pandas

In the code below I'm attempting to reorder a portion of a dataframe and then join it with another portion. The code will sort but when I attempt to run the last line it returns the unsorted frame. Can anyone help with this?

**Code**

```
copied = frame[frame['PLAYVAL'].isin([3,4])].copy()
copied_col = copied['PLAY_EVT']

copied = copied.drop(columns=['PLAY_EVT'],axis=1)
copied = copied.sort_values(['TIME_ELAPSED','SHOTVAL'],ascending=[True,True]).copy()
result = pd.concat([copied_col,copied],axis=1)
```

**Frame**

|  | PLAY_EVT | TIME_ELAPSED | INFO | SHOTVAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 132 | 1of2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 132 | 2of2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 342 | 3of3 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 342 | 2of3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | 342 | 1of3 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 | 786 | 2of2 | 3 |
| 6 | 7 | 786 | 1of2 | 2 |

**Expected Outcome**

|  | PLAY_EVT | TIME_ELAPSED | INFO | SHOTVAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 132 | 1of2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 132 | 2of2 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 342 | 1of3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 342 | 2of3 | 5 |
| 4 | 5 | 342 | 3of3 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 | 786 | 1of2 | 2 |
| 6 | 7 | 786 | 2of2 | 3 |

Comment: Have you tried `ignore_index=True` when using `pd.concat`?

Comment: @frederick-douglas-pearce yes that did not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Must've had something to do with indexes.

```
copied = frame[frame['PLAYVAL'].isin([3,4])]
copied_col = copied['PLAY_EVT'].reset_index(drop=True)

copied = copied.drop(columns=['PLAY_EVT'],axis=1)
copied = copied.sort_values(['TIME_ELAPSED','SHOTVAL'],ascending=[True,True]).reset_index(drop=True)
result = pd.merge(copied_col, copied, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: Nice! I was just about to post `copied = copied.sort_values(['TIME_ELAPSED','SHOTVAL'],ascending=[True,True]).reset_index(drop=True)` in as an answer but you beat me to it. Yes, `pd.concat` is more like a join than a true concatentation of dfs. I think this is probably the most straightforward solution